# Request desktop sites using WKWebView in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, wkwebview

I searched all around but cannot find a way to request the desktop versions of websites without relying on the sites themselves (their own "desktop version" buttons).

Is there a way to do this? I think if I can get it to work in a  UIWebView, it could be done the same way on a WKWebView.

Comment: I don't know the details but things like this are typically done by spoofing the "user-agent" header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably with user agents:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A"])
```

I found the useragent string from this source: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/

Answer (score 4):

If you focus only on iOS 9 version of WKWebView, there is a property `customUserAgent`.

```
// Safari's User Agent (OS X 10.10)
webview.customUserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36";
// Reload webview
[webview reloadFromOrigin];
```

When `customUserAgent`'s value is nil, webview has the default user agent.

In addition, it's better to modify the viewport by using JavaScript for websites judge device type by it.

As for iOS 8 version of WKWebView, NSUserDefaults trick is the only way. Set it before creating a WKWebView instance.