# Xamarin WebView request desktop site

Tags: mobile, webview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to ask, via C#, the iOS and Android WebView components to request the desktop sites?

Comment: For iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764728/request-desktop-sites-using-wkwebview-in-ios

Comment: For Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309796/want-to-load-desktop-version-in-my-webview-using-uastring

Comment: Thank you Sven-Michael. New to Xamarin.forms here. How would I go about calling these functions in the .iOS and .Android versions of the app, respectively?

Comment: You can write a custom renderer for WebView

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to do this per platform

**Android**

In Android you have to implement a custom renderer. Add this into your Android code:

```cs
// this line directly ubleow usings, before namespace declaration
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(DesktopWebViewRenderer))]

// this in your namespace
public class DesktopWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.Settings.UserAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
    }
}
```

**iOS**

Xamarin Forms is using UIWebView, so you have to call

```cs
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.RegisterDefaults(new NSDictionary("UserAgent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A"));
```

some where in your startup code. E.g. in `FinishedLaunching` of your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks man.. It helped me.. its 11: 52 PM here in India.. Good night

Answer (score 1):

Set the user agent string appropriately.  There is no way to do this directly in Xamarin Forms, you would need to write a [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/introduction/) to do that.

iOS UIWebView

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.RegisterDefaults(["UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A"]);
```

iOS9+ WKWebView

```
web.CustomUserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36";
```

Android

```
string agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
web.Settings.UserAgentString = agent;
```